# Get ClassNotFound exception calling greetServlet when GWT Starter app is deployed on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat, service, classnotfound

Environment: Windows 7, Eclipse, GWT 2.5, Tomcat7, Java jre7

Created a GWT Web app project and let the sample code be generated. The app runs fine (w/o any code change) in Eclipse in debug mode. GWT compiled and deployed on Tomcat7 on the same machine.  When a RPC request is made, get `ClassNotFoundException` for service implemention `class GreetingServiceImpl`.  Log from Tomcat7 is below.

Do I need to add some setting that is missing in the generated sample code?  I could not find any answer to this on the web. I am kind of blocked... please advise.

```
----------------
Jan 28, 2013 11:55:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet greetServlet as unavailable
Jan 28, 2013 11:55:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet greetServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.sample.server.GreetingServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
----------------
```

Comment: What is GreetingServiceImpl? Is it deployed in a JAR or is it supposed to get copied directly over to WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Check my answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144527/gwt-servlet-classnotfoundexception#17502080. It should help.

Answer (score 1):

Try unpacking your WAR file and searching to make sure either the JAR file that contains GreetingsServiceImpl is in /WEB-INF/lib OR that the class GreetingsServiceImpl is in /WEB-INF/classes.

It is hard to say which folder to look in, without knowing  what GreetingsServiceImpl is and how it gets incorporated into your build.

Comment: FYI: `GreetingServiceImpl` is a servlet generated in the sample/demo code of a new GWT project (using the Google Plugine for Eclipse wizard, or the gwt-maven-plugin archetype)