# GWT Servlet - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I am learning GWT by following their [StockWatcher tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/stockwatcher). After trying a few things on my own, I got this exception on a servlet:

```
Feb 28, 2013 7:55:00 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Feb 28, 2013 7:55:00 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.sc2.server.GreetingServiceImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

This is the web.xml file where I am configuring the servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.sc2.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bikeapp/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think I'm missing something really basic, but I don't know what. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I think it's obvious the java file GreetingServiceImpl.java isn't at the location com/google/gwt/sc2/server inside your src folder.

Comment: im certain it's in there

Comment: @user1216838 i think this path is incorrect. check once more. com.google.gwt.sc2.server.GreetingServiceImpl

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using eclipse so please check the setting of Default output folder. it should be inside WEB-INF/classes while compile project.

[image]

Comment: It is in that folder, in my case bikeapp/war/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: This fixed my case, (in edit should be set to use default) don't know how this got changed?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The reason was that i created project using GPE (Google Plugin for Eclipse) and tried to follow GWT in action book. But my version of GPE creating a lot of staff insted of just basic project infrastructure. So, if you change your web.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
</web-app>
```

everything should work fine.